# Почему вместо букв появляются вопросительные знаки при заполнении таблицы T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Вот такой код:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees] (
   [Id]  INT  IDENTITY(1,1)  NOT NULL,
   [Name]        VARCHAR (30)  NOT NULL,
   [Surname]     VARCHAR (30)  NOT NULL,
   [Patronymic]  VARCHAR (30)  NULL,
   [DateofBirth] DATE          NOT NULL,
   [Address]     VARCHAR (160) NOT NULL,
   [Position]    INT NOT NULL,
   [Surcharge]   INT NULL, --надбавка
   PRIMARY KEY  ([Id] )
);
```

И вот, что получается:
[Проблема изображенная в gif-ке](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8oC4.jpg)

При заполнении таблицы, если писать кириллицой - символы превращаются в вопросительный знак. Пробовал поменять VARCHAR на NVARCHAR, но не помогло.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Пробовал поменять VARCHAR на NVARCHAR, но не помогло.

Шаг верный, но этого недостаточно, мы знаем что типы отличаются тем, что `NVARCHAR` может хранить `UNICODE`, но он не преобразует данные при вставке в `UNICODE`.

Измененим типы столбцов:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (
   [Id]  INT  IDENTITY(1,1)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   [Name]        NVARCHAR (30)  NOT NULL,
   [Surname]     NVARCHAR (30)  NOT NULL,
   [Patronymic]  NVARCHAR (30)  NULL,
   [DateofBirth] DATE          NOT NULL,
   [Address]     NVARCHAR (160) NOT NULL,
   [Position]    INT NOT NULL,
   [Surcharge]   INT NULL --надбавка
);
```

И добавим **N** (**N'Петров'**) к строковым значениям, тем самым преобразуем данные при вставке в `UNICODE`.

```
INSERT Employees ([Name],[Surname],[Patronymic],[DateofBirth],[Address],[Position],[Surcharge])
VALUES
(N'Иван',N'Федоров',N'Петрович',GETDATE(),N'Где-то там',1,0)
```

Вот так знаки **?????**  больше вас мучать не будут)

**Подробнее:**

> Префикс символьных констант Unicode с буквой N указывает на вход UCS-2
>   или UTF-16, в зависимости от того, используется ли сортировка SC или
>   нет. Без префикса N строка преобразуется в кодовую страницу по
>   умолчанию, которая может не распознавать определенные
>   символы.

И сама ссылка на статью: [nchar and nvarchar](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Спасибо. Работает.